# Determine if first visible cell equal to last

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, cells

please how to determine in vba if first visible (after using filter) cell equals to the last visible cell?

If I have:

A5 = a, B5 = 1

A6 = b, B6 = 2

A7 = c, B7 = 1

A8 = a, B8 = 1

A9 = b, B9 = 2

Then If I filter out "1", column A will be: a, c, a. Then I need to do nothing.

But, when I filter out "2", Column A will be: b, b. Then I need to be C5 for example = b.

This

```
Range("A200").End(xlUp).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
```

I cant use, because it will use also A1, A2, A3 and A4 (I suppose), but I need to be A5 the "last one".

I have this:

```
If Range("A5").End(xlDown).Value <> "first visible cell in Range("A5:A200")" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Šablona").Range("B2").Value = ""
Else
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Šablona").Range("B2").Value = "first visible cell"
End If
```

Comment: Are you using VBA for other things, or would a formula-based solution work for you?

Comment: Formula based would work.

Comment: I have the edge of an idea - I thought I had it, but then noticed a problem. I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

We apply a filter and want to know if the *first* visible cell in column **A** has the same value as the *last* visible cell in column **A**.

This short macro loops over the range, tests for visibility, and performs the test:

```
Sub Roman()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant
    Dim FlipFlop As Boolean

    Set rng = Range("A2:A26")
    FlipFlop = True

    For Each r In rng
        If FlipFlop Then
            If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                v1 = r.Value
                FlipFlop = False
            End If
        Else
            If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                v2 = r.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If v1 = v2 Then
        MsgBox "they are equal"
    Else
        MsgBox "they are not equal"
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

This does not depend on SpecialCells.

Answer (score 1):

ok, figured out:

```
=INDEX(A3:A200;MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3;OFFSET(A3;ROW(A3:A200)-ROW(A3);0));ROW(A3:A200)-ROW(A3)+1)))
```

returns first value, and:

```
=LOOKUP(2;1/((SUBTOTAL(3;OFFSET(A3:A65535;ROW(A3:A65535)-MIN(ROW(A3:A65535));0;1)))*(1-ISBLANK(A3:A65535)));A3:A65535)
```

returns last value.

Thanks for help.